# Offline Gretty Plugin

Tags: gradle, embedded-jetty, gretty

I have a project that runs on gretty and needs to be built without access to the internet.  I have included all the gretty jars locally and am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/akhikhl/gretty/Externalized 
  at org.akhikhl.gretty.GrettyPlugin$_apply_closure62.doCall(GrettyPlugin.groovy:772) 
  at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
  at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
  at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
  at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:145)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:215)
```

What other files are required in order to be able to run gretty offline?  The only way I can get the project running is by letting gradle access the files thru jcenter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gradle appRun --offline`

Reference [Gretty issues](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/137)